# How to completely delete a dynamic array in C and not just a single element

Tags: c

I have to make a function to delete an entire dynamic array, and I'm having trouble thinking what to do with the data that is stored, because if I just use free() I'd be losing memory.

I couldn't find any help in other issues because they mostly talk about deleting a single element, but I want to destroy the array basically.
Thanks

Comment: I don't get it - how do you want to delete array but keep data?

Comment: What i'm saying is that if I just use free(), wouldn't I be losing memory and getting valgrind errors?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: I think he wants to delete the items in the array

Comment: You need to show example code.

Comment: I don't have any code bc i'm simply thinking of the problem, and yes, I want to delete the items in the array and then free the memory correctly. Sorry i can't expres very well

Comment: If the array being allocated is an array of pointers which then point to more allocations, then you'd have to iterate over the array and free each allocated memory, and only then free the original array. Otherwise, you don't "delete elements" just like you **don't** fill any VLA with 0's or something to indicate free or used.

Comment: Just delete what you allocate with `malloc` etc.  If you only call `malloc` once, to create an array, then you only need to call `free` once, with that same array.  If you call `malloc` multiple times, once for an array of pointers, and then again for each pointer in the array to allocate what it points to, then reverse the process:  First call `free` for each pointer in the array, then call it once for the array itself.

Comment: walk through the array deleting elements, then delete the array itself

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is for every `malloc` there should be a `free`.

If it's an array, all the data is stored directly in the array's memory. Freeing the array frees all the elements.

For example, let's say I have a struct called `person`.

```
typedef struct {
  int id;
  char name[20];
} person;
```

If I want to store 8 structs, I allocate an array large enough for 8 structs.

```
person *people = malloc(sizeof(person) * 8);
```

Each thing I assign to the array is *copied* to the array.

```
// `p` uses automatic stack memory which is managed for you
person p = { .id = 23, .name = "Yarrow Hock" };
people[0] = p;  // p is copied to the array's heap memory
```

When I'm done, I free the array. This frees all the structs.

```
free(people);
```

One malloc, one free.

---

An array of pointers is different. If I want to store an array of 8 pointers to my struct, I allocate space for 8 pointers.

```
person **array = malloc(sizeof(person*) * 8);
```

Then I must allocate space for each element. Only the pointer is copied to the array.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    person *p = malloc(sizeof(person));
    p->id = i;
    p->name = "Some One";
    people[i] = p;
}
```

The allocated heap memory for the elements must be managed. How you do that depends on who you decide "owns" the elements.

If it's the array, then the array should free them before freeing itself.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    free(people[i]);
}
free(people);
```

If someone else owns the elements, just free the array. Something else will manage the memory of the elements.

```
free(people);
```

Which you do depends on how your code is designed. For example, if I store a pointer to each person's name in an array.

```
char *names = malloc(sizeof(char*));
for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    names[i] = people[i]->name;
}

// Free only the array.
free(names);
```

When I free `names` I do *not* free the elements. They are part of memory `names` does not "own", it has "borrowed" the memory. If I were to free the elements of `names` then the persons in `people` would be corrupted.

---

What if the struct itself has pointers?

```
typedef struct {
  int id;
  char *name;
} person;
```

They need to be free'd as well. This complicates managing the memory of the array's elements. You need to know details of how the array's elements are managed.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    free(people[i]->name);
    free(people[i]);
}
free(people);
```

Array implementations can deal with this by allowing you to register a function to handle deallocating the elements. For example, [GLib Pointer Arrays](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.64/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html).

```
void free_the_people(gpointer data) {
    person *p = (person*)data;
    printf("Deallocating %s\n", p->name);
    free(p->name);
    free(p);
}

int main() {
    GPtrArray *people = g_ptr_array_new_full(8, free_the_people);

    // Allocate memory for the struct.
    person *p = malloc(sizeof(person));

    // Allocate memory for the string.
    p->name = malloc(40);
    strcpy(p->name, "Yarrow Hock");
    p->id = 23;

    // Copy the pointer to the array.
    g_ptr_array_add(people, p);

    // Call free_the_people on each element, then deallocate the array.
    g_ptr_array_unref(people);
}
```